# Symfony form EntityType::class - How use it to edit data in form (3.2.13)

Tags: forms, symfony, request, symfony-forms

A dropdown selection menu in a Form is available by using a `EntityType` form type. It is usefull if you add data. But when you try to edit data with the same FormType class, your `$request` data are overwritten by your EntityType.

How use the same FormType class when **editing** the data? (eg. editAction in controller) How pass Request `$request` data to FormType fields as "defaults, or selected" for element EntityType::class in FormBuilder? Is there something in $builder->add() method I can use like `if(['choice_value'] !=== null ) xx : yy`?

How to get something like html **select selected**, from Request object and pass it to xxxFormType class and bind to right EntityType::class element there.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

I've looked at [EntityType Field](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/reference/forms/types/entity.html), 
[How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/3.2/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) and lots of StackOverflow posts, but can't find proper solution.

Controller:

```
public function editProdPackageAction(Request $request, ProdPackage $prodPackage)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ProdPackageFormType::class, $prodPackage);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $prodPackage = $form->getData();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($prodPackage);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'MSG#011E');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_package_list');
    }


    return $this->render(':admin/forms/ProdPackage:edit.html.twig',
        [
            'ppg' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );
}
```

Formtype:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'idCatBig',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'label'         => '* category',
                'class'         => 'AppBundle\Entity\ProdCategoryBig',
                'choice_value'  => 'id',
                'choice_label'  => 'shortName',

                'multiple'      => false,
                'expanded'      => false,
            ]
        )
        ->add(
            'dateStart',
            DateType::class,
            [
                'label'                     => '* some date',
                'data'  => new \DateTime('now'),
                'choice_translation_domain' => true,
            ]
        )
        ->add(
            'dateEnd',
            DateType::class,
            [
                'label' => '* till',
                    'data'  => new \DateTime('now'),
            ]
        )
        ->add(
            'packageName',
            TextType::class,
            [
                'label' => '* package',
                'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'default Name'],
                'data'  => 'your default value',
            ]
        )
```

Comment: Your question is hard to read. Remove opinions, clearly state your goals and what you have tried.

Comment: No, it isn't clear.

Comment: I think it is clear, he wants to show the existing data on edit instead of having it overwritten by the default data he is setting for create purposes. I personally use listeners, I doubt there is a way around that, I would be interested though if anyone has a cleaner solution (that also avoids adding code to the controller because I like all my edit functions to look alike)

Comment: Your question is hard to read because of your opinion ("great for adding terrible for editing data", "tons of code", "fight Goliat vs David..") and caps (FORM ENTITY TYPE). You've got an interesting question, but you've messed up. When (at least) two people think your question is hard to read, try to ask questions how you can improve it. Just denying it ("It's all clear here") or shouting a people ("What Is not clear!")  won't help you.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I've upvoted it.

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi - can you please show me full example how use listener to set data I'm trying to reach? (to edit existing data)

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

You are overriding an object by using the `data` option.

https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/reference/forms/types/entity.html#data:

> **( ! )** The `data` option *always* overrides the value taken from the domain data (object) when rendering. This means the object value is also overriden when the form edits an already persisted object, causing it to lose its persisted value when the form is submitted.

## Solution 1: use the controller

So the solution is pretty simple: don't use `data`. Instead, set default values in your `addProdPackageAction` action (or whatever it is called):

```
public function editProdPackageAction(Request $request)
{
    $prodPackage = new ProdPackage();
    $prodPackage->setDateEnd(new Datetime('now'));

    //example: use Request or other controller methods to modify your entity
    if ($this->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $prodPackage->setCreatedByAdmin(true);
    }

    //your form
}
```

## Solution 2: use your entity constructor

Alternatively, you can use your entity constructor method:

```
class ProdPackage
{
    //your attributes
    private $dateEnd;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dateEnd = new Datetime('now');
    }
}
```

Comment: hi I will try to rewrite the question and take note of your observations. Like @Joe Yahchouchi said: "
 
I think it is clear, he wants to show the existing data on edit instead of having it overwritten by the default data he is setting for create purposes."

Comment: what I would like to achieve is to override 'data' field in EntityType::class (and any other) if is not empty in Request $request object (for example method edit is called)

Comment: Add `$prodPackage->setDateEnd(new Datetime('now'));` to your `editProdPackageAction` (and remove `data` from your FormType) and see what happens: the end date will be filled in. Or like your other example: `$car = new Car(); $car->setBrand('Volvo');` will return `<option value="volvo" selected="selected">Volvo</option>` in your form.

Comment: is it possible to use method declared in Entity class  inside form type?

Comment: You can, but I think you shouldn't. I think you're trying to get a workaround. Please explain why my answer isn't what you're looking for, so I can update my answer.

Comment: I'm looking for solution how replace in FormType class $builder ->add('name', EntityType::class,[ ... current value from $request as selected one in form])

Comment: I've got two possible solutions is my answer. Why don't you try them?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do in my form, I set a "pre set data listener" to check whether or not this is an edit or a create

```
function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add(
    'dateStart',
    DateType::class,
    [
    'label' => '* some date'
    //I don't set a data field here because it is an edit
    'choice_translation_domain' => true,
    ]
    )

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        if (!$data || null === $data->getId()) {
            //if the entity does not have an ID it means that this is a new entity not an edit. because all edits have been in the database and have an id
            $builder->add(
            'dateStart',
            DateType::class,
            ['label' => '* some date',
            'data' => new \DateTime('now'), //this is a create so I override my previous setting and set a default data
            'choice_translation_domain' => true,]
            )
        }
    });
}
```

I mainly use this trick to change form fields from required to non required between edits and creates for password fields for example,and sometimes if there is something exceedingly complicated. To change data, honestly, setting default data in constructor is cleaner as Stephan suggests

Comment: It will work for DataType::class but still can't resolve EntityType::class((->add(
            'idCatBig',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'label'         => '* category',
                'class'         => 'AppBundle\Entity\ProdCategoryBig',
                'choice_value'  => 'id',
                'choice_label'  => 'shortName',

                'multiple'      => false,
                'expanded'      => false,
            ]))

Answer (score 0):

Found another interesting solution

in formTypeclass at $builder

```
->add(
                    'trBegin',
                    DateTimeType::class,
                    [
                        'label'       => 'Tourney Begins',
                        'required'    => true,
                        'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                        'time_widget' => 'single_text',
                        'date_format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
                    ]
                )
```

and continuing building form add:

```
        $builder->get('trBegin')->addModelTransformer(
            new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($value) {
                        if (!$value) {
                                return new \DateTime('now + 60 minutes');
                        }

                        return $value;
                },
                function ($value) {
                        return $value;
                }
            )
        );
```

it sets default date at moment when form is created. This method is very usefull also for EntityType object, where you can pass id of field  in form and get selected  your current real choice from database (not all list from the begining) very useful when using EntityField also for editing forms

```
 $builder->get('productCategory')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($id) {
                if (!$id) {
                    return;
                }

                return $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:ProductCategory')->find($id);
            },
            function($category) {
                return $category->getId();
            }
        ));
```